# Java EnumMap; cannot cast the keys to their Enums

Tags: java, casting, enum-map

I'm giving an EnumMap to a method where I try to access the value's as follows:

```
_playerActionTimeout = (Integer) config.get( Config.Table.PLAYER_TIMEOUT );
```

But this is telling me that I cannot cast Config.Table to Config.Table. The Config bit looks like this:

```
static public enum Table
{
    PLAYER_TIMEOUT( "playerTimeout", Integer.class ),
    PLAYER_STARTCHIPS( "playerStartChips", Integer.class ),
    INITIAL_SMALLBLIND( "initialSmallBlind", Integer.class ),
    INITIAL_BIGBLIND( "initialBigBlind", Integer.class ),
    BLIND_INCREASE( "blindIncrease", SortedMap.class ),
    ROUND_STARTTIMEOUT( "roundStartTimeout", Integer.class );
    //
    private final String _xmlTag;
    private final Class _classType;

    Table( String xmlTag, Class classType )
    {
        _xmlTag = xmlTag;
        _classType = classType;
    }

    public final String getXmlTag()
    {
        return _xmlTag;
    }

    public final Class getParameterClass()
    {
        return _classType;
    }
}
```

If i iterate over the EnumMap all the values and keys are present and trace out fine. But when i try to get a value using the Enum, it will be zero and the error occurs.  What am I doing wrong?

As requested. Here is part of the class that creates the config:

```
private EnumMap<Config.Table, Object> _tableConfig;

public void init()
{
if ( _tableConfig == null )
    {
        _tableConfig = new EnumMap<Config.Table, Object>( Config.Table.class );
    }
}
private void parseConfigFile( String definedZoneName ) throws Exception
{
    //try
    {
        /** START of read config file **/
        IXMLElement config = this.loadConfig( "config.xml" );
        if ( config == null )
        {
            throw new Exception( "No config file was found! or XML zones configuration invalid : no zone found" );
        }
        IXMLElement zones = config.getFirstChildNamed( "Zones" );
        //So far so good
        for ( int zoneIndex = 0; zoneIndex < zones.getChildrenCount(); ++zoneIndex )
        {
            IXMLElement xmlZone = zones.getChildAtIndex( zoneIndex );
            if ( xmlZone.getAttribute( "name" ).equalsIgnoreCase( definedZoneName ) )
            {
            //Table config
            {
                IXMLElement tableConfig = xmlZone.getFirstChildNamed( "TableConfig" );
                for ( int tableElIndex = 0; tableElIndex < tableConfig.getChildrenCount(); ++tableElIndex )
                {
                    IXMLElement zoneElement = tableConfig.getChildAtIndex( tableElIndex );

                    for ( Config.Table configTable : Config.Table.values() )
                    {
                        if ( zoneElement.getName().equals( configTable.getXmlTag() ) )
                        {
                            String value = zoneElement.getContent();
                            Class parameterClass = configTable.getParameterClass();
                            if ( parameterClass.equals( Integer.class ) )
                            {
                                _tableConfig.put( configTable, Integer.parseInt( value ) );
                            }
                            else if ( parameterClass.equals( SortedMap.class ) )
                            {
                                SortedMap<Integer, Config.Blinds> increaseBlinds = new TreeMap<Integer, Config.Blinds>();
                                //Loop through all <increase> elements
                                for ( int increaseElIndex = 0; increaseElIndex < zoneElement.getChildrenCount(); ++increaseElIndex )
                                {
                                    IXMLElement increaseElement = zoneElement.getChildAtIndex( increaseElIndex );

                                    String sTime = increaseElement.getFirstChildNamed( "time" ).getContent();
                                    String sSmallBlind = increaseElement.getFirstChildNamed( "smallBlind" ).getContent();
                                    String sBigBlind = increaseElement.getFirstChildNamed( "bigBlind" ).getContent();

                                    Integer time = Integer.parseInt( sTime );
                                    Integer smallBlind = Integer.parseInt( sSmallBlind );
                                    Integer bigBlind = Integer.parseInt( sBigBlind );

                                    Config.Blinds blinds = new Config.Blinds( smallBlind, bigBlind );

                                    increaseBlinds.put( time, blinds );
                                }

                                _tableConfig.put( configTable, increaseBlinds );
                            }
                            else //if ( parameterClass.equals( String.class ) )
                            {
                                _tableConfig.put( configTable, value );
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Stack<String> missingFields = new Stack<String>();

    for ( Config.Zone configZone : Config.Zone.values() )
    {
        if ( !_zoneConfig.containsKey( configZone ) )
        {
            missingFields.add( configZone.getXmlTag() );
        }
    }

    if ( missingFields.size() > 0 )
    {
        throw new Exception( "We were not able to read these Zone settings from the config.xml : " + missingFields.toString() + ". Please check your setup." );
    }

    missingFields.clear();
    for ( Config.Table configTable : Config.Table.values() )
    {
        if ( !_tableConfig.containsKey( configTable ) )
        {
            missingFields.add( configTable.getXmlTag() );
        }
    }

    if ( missingFields.size() > 0 )
    {
        throw new Exception( "We were not able to read these Table settings from the config.xml : " + missingFields.toString() + ". Please check your setup." );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well what's `config`? You haven't given us enough information here. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Using underscores before field names? Why :(, just why :(

Comment: show us how you `put` Objects into the `config` map. it is obvious that the key is `Table` but what is the value ? . Also you should consider using generics: `Class<?> classType` .

Comment: @Superflat , are you sure about `config.get(...)` instead of `_tableConfig.get(...)` ?

Comment: ok, now tell us what error it is, and where it appears, stack trace or compiler error message.

Comment: @rcook I do so in the first 3 lines :) It literally says "Cannot cast Config.Table to Config.Table" at that line of code.

Comment: @A4L Yeah, it's from different classes, I apolagise. _tableConfig get's passed to another class as config.

Comment: @Superflat, make sure that you have in both `EnumMap<Config.Table, Object> _tableConfig;` and `config.get( Config.Table.PLAYER_TIMEOUT );` the same Type for the enum `Config.Table` check thiere packages and see if they are identical. I suspect that you have two different Declarations of that enum Class in different packages (maybe from some other API) and you have imported the on the first source file and the other in the other source file.

Comment: @Superflat, also Try to make a `clean all` and `build all` and see if the error persists, otherwise unless you provide full and minimal compileable source units i dont see how to spot the reason for that error :/